# ExternalAccessory InputStream/OutputStreams are null?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, external-accessory

I am trying to use InputStream/OutputStream synchronously (like normal IOStreams) in order to read/write to a specific bluetooth device. I know it's possible to do this, because we have some objective-C code that works with our gadget - however we are working with a third party c# library and need to get it working in c#.

I have gotten this far:

```
string protocol = <protocol string>
// Attempt to connect to device...
EASession _session = new EASession (myEAAccessory, protocol);
inStream = _session.InputStream;
outStream = _session.OutputStream;
```

I can see that _session has been allocated in memory - Xamarin shows me it now has a non-null pointer and a data type - however both the InputStream and OutputStream are null (therefore I can't open them, as this throws a nullref exception).

How do I get OutputStream and InputStream to not be null?

(I am trying to read lots of apple docs, but their code examples are all in Objective-C, which i only barely understand... and the Objective-C "memory management" statements don't apply?)

**edit** Also, I have checked that myEAAcessory isn't null, and this returns true:

```
myEAAcessory .ProtocolStrings.Contains (protocol);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list the external accessories you're going to use in your Info.plist.

There is some documentation on this on apple's site:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502

Here is a screenshot of how to set this value in Info.plist:
http://screencast.com/t/AYmOWjf8wkL

(This is from here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1635#c1)

Comment: Thankyou! It worked, i now have an InputStream and OutputStream. :)